# Hamming and Manhattan distances

Tags: distance, metric

I have some question regarding to the distance metric.
Can I say that Hamming distance is very similar to the Manhattan distance if I compare two vestors?

Comment: Hamming distance is usually computed for binary data or data which can be recoded into binary (dummy) variables without loss of information. For binary data this distance = Manhattan distance = squared Euclidean distance.

Comment: @ttnphns Hamming distance applies to more than binary vectors. Moreover, when it is applied to binary vectors their components are often viewed as elements of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_2$, which means the (sum of) squared distances can only be $0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 2):

As ttnphns says in comments, for binary vectors these are equivalent. You can easily verify this by considering that both distances are decomposed into looking at each bit component, and check the $2^2$ possible values for comparing two bits. Hamming distance measures how many bits in binary strings are different, which is the same as taking absolute difference of bits and summing them. For binary values, absolute difference is also equivalent to squared difference, so the distance is also equivalent to squared Euclidean norm.